# How to add multiple data within a list?

Tags: c#, .net

```
List<int> userList = new List<int>();

int input = 0;

int names;
int age;

//string numberInput;


while (input != 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ADD NAME TO LIST: ");
    names = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("ADD USER AGE: ");
    age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    userList.Add(new userList { name = names , a = age });

    userList.Add(names);
    input++;
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

userList keeps throwing an error?

userList is a variable but is used like a type

Comment: do you actually have a **userList** type or **class** ?   the line with **new userList** assumes that you do.

Comment: `List<int>.Add(new userList` is completely invalid. You either want a `List<int>` or a `List<userList>`

Comment: (*once you get your app to compile*) - I recommend you then learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: @Igor Attempting to debug code that doesn't compile doesn't sound like the best choice

Comment: As you step through your code at run time check if you get an exception and check the inputs/outputs. If you get an exception see if you can figure out why based on the inputs/outputs and the line of code that is executing.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - yeah, I guess the premise of my comment should be that the app can compile.

Comment: Asking for a name and trying to convert it to an `Int32` is also confusing.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Changing the name of the variable "names" to "name" should help you keep the code clean. Are you attempting to add an 'id' followed by an 'age' to the list or are you trying to add both as an object (id and age are kept in same index)?

Comment: @gkelly - ah i have realised my problem. I do not have class in order to create the object that will store the data! thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably trying to do something like the code below, the best way to practice and see how code works is to create and debug. Only then will you see what is happening the way you want it and what is not working.

For your code to work correctly you will need to create your `List` not from `integers` but from `another class` that has the `name` and `age` `atributor`.

Take a look, I put the `Users` class to see what it looks like.

```
class Users
{
    public string names { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public Users(string vnames, int vage)
    {
        names = vnames;
        age = vage;
    }
}
```

Already the function that collects the data of the user must create the `list` of `users`.

```
List<Users> userList = new List<Users>();
```

After that, just collect the data and put it on the list.

```
userList.Add(new Users(names, age));
```

Take a look at the full function now.

```
    private static void CreateList()
    {
        List<Users> userList = new List<Users>();

        for (int i = 0; i != 2; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ADD NAME TO LIST: ");
            var names = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("ADD USER AGE: ");
            var age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            userList.Add(new Users(names, age));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Debug line by line and see what happens is beautiful.